# How do you use pdfjs-dist with Angular Elements for Internet Explorer

Tags: angular, internet-explorer, pdf.js, angular-elements, pdfjs-dist

How do you correctly import pdfjs-dist and use the es5 version for Internet Explorer?

I am using Angular 8 and Custom Elements, what I have done so far is

```
npm install --save pdfjs-dist
```

Then in my component I import the script:

```
import * as pdfjs from 'pdfjs-dist'
```

and then I will create a variable

```
pdfjs: any
```

and use the functions like

```
this.pdfjs.getDocument()
```

This will work perfectly fine for Chrome, but in IE will get errors like Object action not supported. Which is expected I guess because it's not using the es5 files.

I tried to modify the pdfjs-dist in the node modules to resolve to the es5 folder, but at the end when I load my component I got an error saying Weakset undefined or something like that.

I also tried manually imported the scripts dynamically and append it by using `document.createElement('script')` and `document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0].appendChild(sc)`. This method will work the best, but performance wise it's very bad because it needs to wait for the scripts to finish loading before you can actually do anything.

What is the proper way to use this package for IE? The documentation for this library and Internet Explorer itself are just absolutely trash.

Comment: I suggest keep the folder and files as it is in the node_modules but try to import the file like below `import * as pdfjsLib from 'pdfjs-dist/es5/build/;`. It may help you to reference the ES5 files for the IE browser. You can make a test on your side and let us know about your test results.

Comment: Yes I have tried that but it will give an error saying 
Cannot found module 'pdfjs-dist/es5/build'

Comment: If possible can you share the sample Angular project? We can see how actually you are trying to use it. You can remove all the confidential information from the sample. We do not require any private information. Thanks for your understanding.